# C using sha2 hashing function

Tags: c, sha

How to use hashing function

```
void sha2( const unsigned char *input, int ilen,
           unsigned char output[32] )
{
    sha2_context ctx;

    sha2_starts( &ctx );
    sha2_update( &ctx, input, ilen );
    sha2_finish( &ctx, output );

    memset( &ctx, 0, sizeof( sha2_context ) );
}
```

I tried

```
sha2(InpData, sizeof(InpData), OutData)
```

but as a result I get trashed data.

Comment: What's the point of the `memset`?

Comment: @CarlNorum The only point of the `memset` would be not to leave SHA-2 context on the stack that could be used to reverse engineer the original string. The hash is resilient to reversing, the context state may not be. Of course in this case there's the whole issue of the original string not being overwritten too... :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the declaration of `InpData` we can't know for sure, ([Please, post a short, compilable example](http://ccsse.org/)), but the probability is that `InpData` is a pointer of some sort, as opposed to an array. The `sizeof()` operator, when applied to a pointer, will not evaluate to the size of the pointed-at allocated storage, but to the size of the pointer: typically 4 or 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it with the data, the length and the buffer where you want your output;

```
char* data = "my data to hash";
int datalen = strlen(data);       // or if binary data, the size of your input
unsigned char buffer[32];         // The buffer to receive the result

sha2(data,datalen,buffer);
```

Note that the data received in the buffer is binary data (32*8=256 bits if it's SHA-256), so you'll want to hex/base64/etc. encode it before displaying the result to a screen.

EDIT: Extremely simple and hackish hex encoding entirely without clean code points :)

```
char* hexencode(void* data, int len)
{
  char* outdata = malloc(len*2+1);
  char* tmp = outdata;
  unsigned char* indata = (char*)data;
  while(len--)
  {
    *tmp++ = "0123456789abcdef"[(*indata)>>4];
    *tmp++ = "0123456789abcdef"[(*indata++)&0xf];
  }
  *tmp = 0;
  return outdata;
}
```

Comment: it dosent help, still getting trash data but a little bit longer
im getting : ĹWç=pÓK1Ău!SŕĘDđˇá; ŞR
                          ň|éG?-RcşáUË6ŕÚíÄÇÎ]«ts

While correct hash is : d7a8fbb307d7809469ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb762d02d0bf37c9e592

Comment: Read the note at the bottom, your desired result is hex encoded binary, while the result from sha2 is just plain binary.

Comment: How to simply encode it to asci in C, sry for newbie ask, im new in C?

Comment: @user2304765 Added a simple hex encoding. If you're not getting the correct result, we need to know what you're trying to encode to try to repeat the result, so you'll need to add some code.

Comment: still dosent work, here are warnings http://wklej.to/JuJ2f ,  source: http://wklej.to/ljb6k

Comment: @user2304765 I think you need to add more detail to your question what you're trying to do, the code you posted reads a character at a time, seems to try to checksum the character with SHA256 and then writes the same character to the serial port. Are you meaning to checksum more than one character at a time?

Comment: The point is make checksum from inpdata by sha256 and write it to OutData, and next send. thats all. inpdata can be one character or over a dozen